# Why the swap partition?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, swap

I always encrypt my Ubuntu installations.  Currently I have /boot installed on a flash drive and two encrypted partitions: / and swap.  In order to log in I have to enter pass phrases for both / and the swap partitions. Why does Ubuntu require a swap partition as opposed to a paging file like Windows?  When I first started to play around with Linux years ago, I vaguely remember installing Open Suse in Virtual Box and, unless I'm dreaming, I seem to remember Open Suse creating a paging file on /.  Is it possible to create a paging file on / under Ubuntu so's to avoid an additional partition?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on a Paging file being to be created in Open Suse since I have no prior experience with it. However Swap is the paging partition for Linux.

The following is excerpted from [SwapFaq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) (by [Contributors to the Ubuntu documentation wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/License)):

> #### What is swap?
>
> Swap space is the area on a hard disk which is part of the Virtual
> Memory of your machine, which is a combination of accessible physical
> memory (RAM) and the swap space. Swap space temporarily holds memory
> pages that are inactive. Swap space is used when your system decides
> that it needs physical memory for active processes and there is
> insufficient unused physical memory available. If the system happens
> to need more memory resources or space, inactive pages in physical
> memory are then moved to the swap space therefore freeing up that
> physical memory for other uses. Note that the access time for swap is
> slower therefore do not consider it to be a complete replacement for
> the physical memory. Swap space can be a dedicated swap partition
> (recommended), a swap file, or a combination of swap partitions and
> swap files.
>
> #### Why do I need swap?
>
> Memory consuming programs Sometimes, a large program (like
> LibreOffice, Neverwinter Nights, or a video editor) make the entire
> system need extra memory. A significant number of the pages used by
> these large programs during its startup may only be used for
> initialization and then never used again. The system can swap out
> those pages and free the memory for other programs or even for the
> disk cache. In these cases, swap will be used to help the system
> handle any extra load.
>
> **Hibernation (suspend-to-disk)** The hibernation feature (suspend-to-disk) writes out the contents of RAM to the swap partition
> before turning off the machine. Therefore, your swap partition should
> be at least as big as your RAM size. The hibernation implementation
> currently used in Ubuntu, swsusp, needs a swap or suspend partition.
> It cannot use a swap file on an active file system.
>
> **Unforeseeable Circumstances** Unforeseeable events can and will happen (a program going crazy, some action needing much more space
> than you thought, or any other unpredictable combination of events).
> In these cases, swap can give you an extra delay to figure out what
> happened, or to finish what you are working on.
>
> **Optimizing memory usage** Since mechanical hard drives are considerably slower than RAM (SSD - Solid State Drive - storage is not
> as slow as physical drives, but still slower than RAM), when you need
> a file (be it a data file like a video, executables like Firefox, or
> libraries), the Linux kernel reads the file into RAM and keeps it
> there, so that the next time you need it, it is already in RAM and
> data access is much faster. The portions of RAM that accelerate disk
> read are called "cached memory." You will notice that they make a huge
> difference in terms of responsiveness. The Linux kernel automatically
> moves RAM reserved by programs--but not really used--into swap, so
> that it can serve the better purpose of extending cached memory.
>
> **Optimizing Swap performance** Because swap space uses a disk device, this can cause performance issues in any system that uses swap space
> significantly because the system itself may also be using the same
> disk device at the same time that it is required for swap operations.
> One way to reduce this problem is to have swap space on a different
> physical drive so that the competition for that resource is either
> reduced or eliminated.

For a more in-depth revision and understanding of all the components, feel free to check out the community Wiki: [SwapFAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)